# Overloading Boost Multi_Index find operation

Tags: c++, search, boost, iterator, multi-index

I have a `boost Multi_index` container in shared memory which keeps some data for performing fast search by multiple processes on same machine.

```
typedef multi_index_container<
    MyData, 
        indexed_by<    
            random_access<>,  // keep insertion order
            ordered_non_unique< member<MyData, time_t, &MyData::timestamp> >
        > 
> myContType;
```

so I would like to perform a search in this container via timestamp property something like that:

```
myContType_by_time& idIndex = myCont.get<1>();
    myContType_by_time::iterator itTime = idIndex.find(timestamp);
```

But the problem is I'm not looking for the exact match. What I am searching is the first item whose predecessor has a value less then the searched time.

Let me give an example, lets assume in my container there are items like that (with this insertion order):

```
    1       2       3      4       5       6
{109345, 109348, 109352, 109355, 109358, 109362, }
```

and when I perform a search with `109354` I'm expecting to find the item `4` because it is the first item whose predecessor is smaller then the search criteria.

Is it possible to imlpement this kind of special searching mechanism with index for fast searching instead of searching the whole array and look for the condition one by one? (the array can have more than 100000 items)

Thanks.

Not: I'm working with Visual Studio 2008 VC++.

Answer (score 1):

```
myContType_by_time::iterator itTime = idIndex.lower_bound(timestamp);
if(itTime!=idIndex.begin())--itTime;
```

Comment: But if i use lower_bound(timestamp) doesn't it look for the timestamp again? Since there is no match it will not return anything am i wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `lower_bound(x)`  returns the first element *not less* than `x`.